# How can I search for an image in cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

How could I search a cloudinary image for its `public_id`? It would be for when I upload an image to check if it already exists, this way I would not have duplicate images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Search API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/search_api) or the [get details of a single resource](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_the_details_of_a_single_resource) through the [Admin API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api).

Having said that, the [Upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference) supports a parameter called `overwrite` which is set to `True` by default. You can set that to `False` in your code and perform your upload as before. In the response, you'll get a field called `existing` set to `True` or `False` indicating the result. If existing is `False` the image you passed would be uploaded since no resource existed with that `public_id`. When `True`, the response contains details of the resource that exists in your account under that `public_id`.

If you want to avoid duplicate images and not just checking the existence of a resource by `public_id`, then you can grab the `ETag` of every resource from the response of each Upload call and store that in your database alongside the `public_id`. The `ETag` returned in the API response is just an MD5 digest of the file itself so you can calculate that locally and compare with the relevant record for that (or all) `public_id` you have and decide whether it's the same file, in which case skip the upload, or overwrite if a new image is uploaded.